# How to make JS files stored in Github repository deployed to Heroku served via Amazon CDN

Tags: heroku, github, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am having a github repository auto deployed to Heroku. Basically what I want to do is to serve all the static files in the repository using Amazon Cloudfront CDN.. Do I need to pull my github repository to Amazon S3 and how to achieve the CDN served files while my repository being auto-deployed to Heroku..

Right now all the static assets are being served from Heroku as there is no CDN involved as of now..

I want to serve the static files via CDN while still retaining the auto deploy feature of Heroku ...

How can I achieve the above said functionality?

Do I need to upload the static assets individually to S3?

Comment: Just point CloudFront at your Heroku URL.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a CloudFront Origin, then update the DNS for your website to point a CNAME record to your CloudFront origin instead of your Heroku application.

So, right now, let's say your Heroku app is called: my-app.

This means that if you view your app on Heroku, you will go to http://my-app.herokuapp.com

If you then create a CloudFront origin and point it to my-app.herokuapp.com, you will get a new CloudFront domain. Something like myid.cloudfront.net

So what you can do next is update the DNS for your website (www.my-app.com) to and create a CNAME record such that

www.my-app.com -> my-id.cloudfront.net

This will make all requests to your website go through CloudFront first -- this way the CloudFront CDN will have a chance to cache your static assets properly and speed it up after the first request.

You can then configure CloudFront to set the cache times for these assets.